# How To make ajax call authenticated with yourAuthCookie

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, cookies

I am making an ajax call to a login protected page like this

```
  $(".box01 .selproduct").live("click", function(e) {
    var color = $(this).parent('.box01').find('.color').val();
    var size = $(this).parent('.box01').find('.size').val();
    var pid=$(this).parent('.box01').find('.hdinput').val();
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;

    var data = { submit: "selected",size:size,color:color,pid: pid};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pathname ,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        },
        complete: function(data) {

        }
    });
    return false;
```

as the page is protected by login this is not returning me anything.When i checked my cookie I found a cookie

> yourAuthCookie

which holds a string value.Is there any way that i can modify my ajax call with this cookie and make it authenticated to requested page?

Comment: I believe, the session variable is persisted for logged user so cookie is a minor problem. I wouldn't base security on cookies on my sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
var pathname = window.location.href;
```